# Using setItemChecked in custom listview

Tags: android, checkbox, checkedtextview

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.parse.ParseRelation;
import com.parse.ParseUser;

public class FriendsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    ViewHolder holder;
    Context context;
    List<FriendsList> friendsList;
    ParseUser user = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
    ParseRelation<ParseUser> friendsRelation;

    public FriendsListAdapter(Context context) {  
        this.context = context;
        friendsList = new ArrayList<FriendsList>();
        friendsRelation = user.getRelation("Friends");
    }  

    public void add(FriendsList object,int position){
        friendsList.add(position,object);
    }

    public void remove(int position){
        friendsList.remove(position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return friendsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return friendsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View v = convertView;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(v == null){
            v = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.friends_list_item,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(v);
            v.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)v.getTag();
        }
        Typeface roboto = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
        holder.listText.setTypeface(roboto);
        holder.listText.setText(friendsList.get(position).username);
        Glide.with(context).load(friendsList.get(position).profilePicture).into(holder.profile_picture);
        return v;
    }

    static class ViewHolder{
        TextView listText;
        CheckedTextView friendsBox;
        ImageView profile_picture;
        ViewHolder(View v){
            listText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.friend_username);
            friendsBox = (CheckedTextView)v.findViewById(R.id.isFriend);
            profile_picture = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.friendsProfilePicture);
        }
    }
    public void Toast(String text,int length){
        Toast.makeText(context, text, length).show();
    }
}
```

I want to be able to use the setItemChecked Method in my listview adapter that way I can parse some data and check the box based on a boolean. How can I implement this in my adapter?

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do.

```
friendsList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.friendsList);
    friendsList.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
    friendsList.setItemChecked(0, true);
    friendsList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             CheckedTextView cv =(CheckedTextView)view.findViewById(R.id.isFriend);
             cv.toggle();
        }

    });
```

Comment: What is your minimum API level?

Comment: @corsair992 My Minimum is 16.

Comment: OK, you can set a selector checkbox drawable that is checked on `state_activated`, and assign it to the `checkMark` attribute in the `CheckedTextView`. This should work post-ICS.

Answer (score 0):

In the `getView()` method of the `Adapter`:

```
final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.product_checkbox);
    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                // The checkbox is checked, then set the list item as selected
                ((ListView) parent).setItemChecked(position, true);
            } else {
                // The checkbox is unchecked, then  set the list item as unselected
                ((ListView) parent).setItemChecked(position, false);
            }
        }
    });
```

You can also use an OnClickListener instead of the OnCheckedChangeListener:

```
checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Get the checkbox state
            boolean isChecked = checkBox.isChecked();
            if (isChecked) {
                // The checkbox is checked, then set the list item as selected
                ((ListView) parent).setItemChecked(position, true);
            } else {
                // The checkbox is unchecked, then  set the list item as unselected
                ((ListView) parent).setItemChecked(position, false);
            }
        }
    });
```

Remember to set as `final` the `int position` and the `ViewGroup parent` variables in the `getView()` method.